# Nested properties are not reactive in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a component with nested properties:

```
 data () {
   return {
     config: {
       headers: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
       pagination: {
         currentPage: externalService.data.page
         totalPages: externalService.data.totalPages
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

When `externalService.data.totalPages` is changed (by other component), the child components are not reactive to this, since maybe the nested reference in `config` was changed, but not `config` itself.

I can use watchers to solve it, but I wish to know what would be the declarative (and optimal) solution for it. I'm not a fan of imperative approach when it comes to ClientSide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `externalService.data.totalPages` is an integer. Integer are passed by value and not by reference. So it's a completely normal behavior an you should indeed use a watcher.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to simply wrap the primitive props with an object, so instead of watching, the reactive nature simply works.

Comment: Yes, that's actually the best solution

Comment: Chen, could you elaborate on what you mean by wrapping the primitive props with an object?

Comment: @HJohnson like from `1` to `{value: 1}`